# Data source Change causing relationships to drop

Tags: powerbi

I am currently using PBIX with hosted SQL server as datasource. I am moving to Azure and I have a copy of database migrated to Azure.
Now when I change the data source setting from hosted SQL server to Azure and refresh/apply changes my visuals break and the cause of issue is relationship being dropped between dim table and fact table.

The table structure (table name, column names) is the same as its migrated from hosted server to Azure server.

Any one knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change the following settings which are annoyingly on by default.

[image]

Comment: I already have this option Turned OFF. I am using Direct Query Method.